# bind a char* to a string

Tags: c++, string, bind, c-strings

I would like to bind a char to a string, but I dont know how to do it:
The idea is that I have a function ***void f(char* mychar)*** that updates the value of ***mychar***. and I would like to pass this update into a string.

the code must look like :

```
char* mychar = new char[128];

string mystring;

\\bind mystring with mychar
.....

f(mychar);

std::cout << mychar << std::endl ;
std::cout << mystring << std::endl
```

and the value returned by mychar and mystring must be the same.

any ideas please?

many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A string can change its internal buffer so even if you could create a string that uses a particular buffer, after common mutations, it might have a different backing buffer.

For example, it can reallocate the buffer based on a [`string::reserve(...)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/reserve/) call.

[`string::c_str`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) says

> The pointer returned points to the internal array currently used by the string object to store the characters that conform its value.
>
> Both `string::data` and `string::c_str` are synonyms and return the same value.
>
> The pointer returned **may be invalidated by further calls** to other member functions that modify the object.

and the notes for C++98 have this warning

> A program shall not alter any of the characters in this sequence.

which you seem to want `f(mychar)` to do.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to initialize `mychar` first.  Then the rest is simple:

```
char* mychar = new char[128];
mychar[0] = 'A';
mychar[1] = '\0';
std::string mystring(mychar);

std::cout << mychar << std::endl;
std::cout << mystring << std::endl;
```

EDIT:  But I just realized this doesn't answer your question, this code only helps at initialization.  See @Mike's answer.

Answer (score -1):

Do I get you right that you simply want both variables referencing the same string?
If that should work:

```
string mystring;
char* mychar = mystring.data();
```

The data method returns a pointer to the string data which is simply the start address of the characters -> a char*.

Regards

Comment: This will not work. If you add character to the existing string, it may reallocate internal pointer and it will do it when string is large enough.
Also, data member function returns const char* which cannot be assigned to char*.